# fit div container height no longer it's content

Tags: css

[image: fit container]

I want to fit div container height  no longer it's content

and also remain the scrolling ,

that mean remove the down black area and fit to green area

when you scrolling down you will see extended black area , want to fit it's content

example :
https://jsfiddle.net/e53cxw0r/
please review this example to show the issue

```
<style>
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
.section {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.style_content {
    color: #27272a;
    max-width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9;

}
    .sidebar_panel {display: flex; flex: 0 1 auto;  float:right;    width: fit-content;overflow-y: auto;}

    .panel2 {display:flex;    flex :1;  width:fit-content;}

</style>

<div  id="container" style="height:auto;background-color:#000;height:200px;" class="sidebar_panel panel2">
    <div style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;width:300px;; margin:0;">
                
                            
                            
                            <div id="child1" style="padding:0px;background-color:green; position: relative;  direction: rtl;width:100%;min-height:40px;height:0;;">
                                <div  style="width: 280px;; ">
                                    <div id="child" style="background:red;flex: 0 0 auto; width: 1400px;  transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);">
                                        <section class="section">
                                            <div class="style_content container">
                                                <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
                                                 <div><p>that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.
                                                 that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.</p></div>
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">click me</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="child2" style="padding:0px;background-color:green; position: relative;  direction: rtl;width:100%;min-height:40px;height:0;;">
                                <div  style="width: 280px;; ">
                                    <div id="child" style="background:red;flex: 0 0 auto; width: 1400px;  transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);">
                                        <section class="section">
                                            <div class="style_content container">
                                                <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
                                                 <div><p>that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.
                                                 that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.</p></div>
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">click me</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  


                            <div id="child3" style="padding:0px;background-color:green; position: relative;  direction: rtl;width:100%;min-height:40px;height:0;;">
                                <div  style="width: 280px;; ">
                                    <div id="child" style="background:red;flex: 0 0 auto; width: 1400px;  transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);">
                                        <section class="section">
                                            <div class="style_content container">
                                                <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
                                                 <div><p>that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.
                                                 that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.</p></div>
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">click me</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  


                            <div id="child4" style="padding:0px;background-color:green; position: relative;  direction: rtl;width:100%;min-height:40px;height:0;;">
                                <div  style="width: 280px;; ">
                                    <div id="child" style="background:red;flex: 0 0 auto; width: 1400px;  transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);">
                                        <section class="section">
                                            <div class="style_content container">
                                                <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
                                                 <div><p>that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.
                                                 that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.</p></div>
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">click me</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="child5" style="padding:0px;background-color:green; position: relative;  direction: rtl;width:100%;min-height:40px;height:0;;">
                                <div  style="width: 280px;; ">
                                    <div id="child" style="background:red;flex: 0 0 auto; width: 1400px;  transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);">
                                        <section class="section">
                                            <div class="style_content container">
                                                <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
                                                 <div><p>that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.
                                                 that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.</p></div>
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">click me</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                  
                
    </div>  
        
</div>
```

Comment: @kairav-thakar , can you help in this

Comment: @kairav-thakar , I'm not solved it yet , I'm waiting you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

This is just my personal opinion, but your HTML has a lot of inline styles, which I don't really think is best practice and makes for messy markup. The solution I propose below simplifies your HTML and reuses classes for CSS.

In essence, your markup wasn't leveraging flexbox correctly. [This is a pretty handy resource for CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and should help you in the future.

I hope this helps.

/*********/

/ *Revised* /

/*********/

What about this? I tried to preserve as much of your code as possible. To re-iterate the above, I really think you should consider cleaning up a lot of the inline styles found in your HTML.

```css
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
.section {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.style_content {
    color: #27272a;
    max-width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9;

}
    .sidebar_panel {display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex: 1 1 auto; float:right;    width: fit-content;overflow-y: scroll;}
  
  .sidebar_panel > div {
    display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

 .sidebar_panel > div  > div{
    overflow: hidden;
  }

    .panel2 {display:flex;    flex :1;  width:fit-content;}
```

```html
<div   style="height:auto;background-color:#000;height:200px;" class="sidebar_panel panel2">
    <div style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;width:300px;; margin:0;">
                
                            
                            
                            <div id="child1" style="padding:0px;background-color:green; position: relative;  direction: rtl;width:100%;min-height:40px;height:0;;">
                                <div  style="width: 280px;; ">
                                    <div id="child" style="background:red;flex: 0 0 auto; width: 1400px;  transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);">
                                        <section class="section">
                                            <div class="style_content container">
                                                <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
                                                 <div><p>that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.
                                                 that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.</p></div>
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">click me</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="child2" style="padding:0px;background-color:green; position: relative;  direction: rtl;width:100%;min-height:40px;height:0;;">
                                <div  style="width: 280px;; ">
                                    <div id="child" style="background:red;flex: 0 0 auto; width: 1400px;  transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);">
                                        <section class="section">
                                            <div class="style_content container">
                                                <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
                                                 <div><p>that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.
                                                 that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.</p></div>
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">click me</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  


                            <div id="child3" style="padding:0px;background-color:green; position: relative;  direction: rtl;width:100%;min-height:40px;height:0;;">
                                <div  style="width: 280px;; ">
                                    <div id="child" style="background:red;flex: 0 0 auto; width: 1400px;  transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);">
                                        <section class="section">
                                            <div class="style_content container">
                                                <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
                                                 <div><p>that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.
                                                 that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.</p></div>
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">click me</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  


                            <div id="child4" style="padding:0px;background-color:green; position: relative;  direction: rtl;width:100%;min-height:40px;height:0;;">
                                <div  style="width: 280px;; ">
                                    <div id="child" style="background:red;flex: 0 0 auto; width: 1400px;  transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);">
                                        <section class="section">
                                            <div class="style_content container">
                                                <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
                                                 <div><p>that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.
                                                 that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.</p></div>
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">click me</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="child5" style="padding:0px;background-color:green; position: relative;  direction: rtl;width:100%;min-height:40px;height:0;;">
                                <div  style="width: 280px;; ">
                                    <div id="child" style="background:red;flex: 0 0 auto; width: 1400px;  transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);">
                                        <section class="section">
                                            <div class="style_content container">
                                                <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>
                                                 <div><p>that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.
                                                 that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.that is for test.</p></div>
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank">click me</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                  
                
    </div>  
        
</div>
```

Comment: that is not I want ,please  preserve this code , it's making small preview of child div code
transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);

Comment: that is your code after I update as I I want , it's make the same issue , https://jsfiddle.net/eh21pr6m/

Comment: Please see my updated response. Is this what you meant?

Comment: eric you do not remove extended space after last child , you make  extended space after every child , please see ,https://jsfiddle.net/e53cxw0r/ I want exactly like that without last down exteneded black space

Comment: Hello Sami, what about now? 

What you are asking for isn't entirely clear.

You want to remove the black space but also maintain scrolling for the element. Removing the black space means that your green boxes fit the container and there's no overflow, so there's nothing to scroll.

If this is not what you're looking for, please articulate clearly what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks for you interested about my issue, but I found it's difficult to solve , for that I set the child as fixed height , but it's in the design is Incompatable , look at this image , https://ibb.co/2ZpzwqZ  , as you see , childerns is viarable height , not fixed

Comment: For what I do, I make some designs , and I want to make some samll previews for this designs , and as you know height is diffrenets in all designs

Comment: Hi Sami, I would refer to the link in my original answer (the CSS flexbox guide). If you have elements with variable heights, you can't reasonably expect them to look good in containers with fixed heights. 

At this point I would recommend revising your design approach and trying to leverage flexbox more effectively.

Comment: Hi eric , Can you make some childs divs with diffrent colors diffrent height , and make small preview of it in container ,  your answer code but new childs diifrent contains , I think you can do it , thanks again

Comment: note : please remove min-height:40px; it's make height for all childs 40px; but I want height auto  fit content

Comment: Hello Sami, I will not simply do things at your request. Please try to refer to [StackOverflow's best practices when asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). 

You need to make an effort and attempt to demonstrate what you've tried and what you expected to happen. 

At the minimum, why don't you try to make a new JsFiddle using some of my suggestions and with the different divs you mention in your comment? I'd be happy to review that.

Comment: Thanks Eric , you already fixed original issue ,I will try fix the others